# $locationProvider.html5Mode not perfect working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, routes

My URL is:

http://192.168.110.4/produtos/3-fazer-a-limpeza-da-casa-juntos-une-os-casais

My Base is: /

When access by normal link works properly. But when I refresh the page, the Angular loses the base URL.

My Routes:

```js
function Config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/produtos', {
                    templateUrl: 'moduloprodutos/template/index.html',
                    controller: 'produtosController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                })
                .when('/produtos/:subcategoriaSlug', {
                    templateUrl: 'moduloprodutos/template/interna.html',
                    controller: 'produtosController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                })
                .when('/produtos/:subcategoriaSlug/:produtoSlug', {
                    templateUrl: 'moduloprodutos/template/descricao_produto.html',
                    controller: 'produtosController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    }
```

The URL is not interpreted completely, leaving as a base, from `/produtos`.

But my base is `/`, which can be?

HTACCESS:

```html
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

# Required to allow direct-linking of pages so they can be processed by Angular
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]

</ifModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't reach the URL @Shelon. The name of your function is Config but are you sure that it's being fired by angularjs's call to config? Your function should be called by the following:

```
angular.module('NAMEOFAPP').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', Config)
```